# How to concate imagefolder datasets on Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, concatenation

I have a question regarding the concate function on Pytorch. I could not find any answers that could help me solve this. I have this code:

```
train_val_folder = root + "train_val_data/"
train_set1_original = datasets.ImageFolder(train_val_folder, transform=train_val_transform_croponly)
train_val_modified = datasets.ImageFolder(train_val_folder, transform=train_val_transform)

train_val_dataset= torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset([train_set1_original , train_val_modified ])
classes = train_val_dataset.classes

train_val_length = len(train_val_dataset)

print(train_val_length)
```

```
AttributeError: 'ConcatDataset' object has no attribute 'classes'
```

Is there an easier way to concate the original and transformed datasets while preserving .classes from ImageFolder?